# Latitude and Longitude to Place name or City in .NET

Tags: .net, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have a set of latitude and longitude values (and a geodetic datum?).  I want to use these to get a place name or a city.  Is there some way to do this in .NET?

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702309/need-a-list-of-all-countries-in-the-world-with-a-longitude-and-latitude-coordin

Comment: That's about getting back country names.  I don't want that, I need city or place name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name for this is Reverse Geocoding. There are many providers for such a service. One is google. Have a look at their developers section:

[Google Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding)

You can just format the required URL and use a [Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.NET.WEBCLIENT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true) to download the Json:

```
Using client As New Net.WebClient()
   Return client.DownloadString(address)
End Using
```

You will then need to [parse the Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191141/parse-json-in-net-runtime) data to extract the street name

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a web service. [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/) is one such source that is free.

Comment: @SachinKainth they have several client libraries: http://www.geonames.org/export/client-libraries.html