# how to do Json parsing Using newtonsoft.json in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
{"Contacts":[{"number":"+919632545302"} ,
 {"number":"09868333140"},{"number":"099-713-55036"}]}
```

This My Json Data i want Parse and Store all Phone number in String by comma separated.

string="+919632545302,09868333140,099-713-55036"

please help me i have tried but i am unable to do this  .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2191164/2179864

Comment: But i am unable to declare value please help me in that string Jsondata= ' {"Contacts":['+'{"number":"+919632545302"}  ,'+'  {"number":"09868333140"}  ,'+'  {"number":"099-713-55036"}]}';  please declare it am getting Compile time Error @Zigma

Comment: compile time Error even i tried @this also but not working pleas help me in that

Comment: too many characters in character literal this Error actully coming

Comment: you need to learn something about how to use JSON in c#. After that you will understand what is the error.

Comment: I am having Problem Only initialize please help me on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@` at the beginning of your JSON string and escape `"` character by doubling each of them (`""`) :

```
string data = @"{""Contacts"":[{""number"":""+919632545302""} 
, 
 {""number"":""09868333140""}  
,  
{""number"":""099-713-55036""}]}";
```

Then you can do this to get all contact numbers as comma separated string :

```
JObject json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(data);
JArray contacts = (JArray)json["Contacts"];
string result = string.Join(",", contacts.Select(o => o["number"].ToString()));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: can i have ur email id i need some IMP talk wid u